# How to configure pip search to use multiple URLs?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I used the [pip.conf](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/) user guide to customize my `pip` installation to pull from two internal Artifactory URLs instead of the default public one. I would now like to configure `pip search` to the same restriction. While I see an `--index` option which works great, I don't see a way to provide a second URL to search.  I tried using `--index` twice but that didn't work.  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible. pip search doesn't respect extra-index-url:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/395